# Limit query results based on an expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am having a problem limiting my query results to a related table value.

```
SELECT Roster.UserID, Roster.[WM DOH], Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2) AS YearsOfService,     tblAccrual.WeeksAccrual
FROM Roster, tblAccrual
WHERE (([tblAccrual]![Years]<[YearsOfService]))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, Roster.[WM DOH], Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2), tblAccrual.WeeksAccrual;
```

My query should return the number of accrual weeks based on years of service.  When I run the query it asks in an input box for the YearsOfService. What I am looking for is to have the appropriate accrual value return for teh user based on their years of service. When I remove the "Where" piece it returns all combinations for the various years of service value.  I only want the one corresponding to their years of service. In excel I have a formula like...

```
Today - Date of Hire / 365 = Years of service
if(years of service <2,0, if(years of service <7,2, if Years of service <15,3, 4)))
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to the alias `YearsOfService` in the Where statement, use something like:

```
WHERE (([tblAccrual]![Years]<Round((Date()-[WM DOH])/365,2)))
```

From the number of parentheses, it seems you are building using the query design window, it can help to put a criterion under the aliased column to see what MS Access suggests.